# Vertex locations of Dessin w/h Circle packing in Discrete Dessin d'Enfant

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, graph-embeddings

I'm reading the following paper.
[Bowers, Philip L., and Kenneth Stephenson. Uniformizing Dessins and BelyiMaps via Circle Packing. Vol. 170. No. 805. American Mathematical Soc., 2004.](https://www.math.fsu.edu/%7Ebowers/Papers/dessin.pdf)

In the paper, Fig.3 is supposed to represent the dessin in Fig.1 (Right hand-side) but I can't seem to figure out the vertix locations of $\infty$-vertex.

** In fig.3 below, following this paper I use a solid dot to mark 0-vertices, a small x to denote 1-vertices, and the empty circle to represent $\infty$-vertices.

### my attempt of marking the vertex locations in Fig.3

Here, (hopefully) I could find the locations of 0 and 1 vertices. but i'm not sure which of the circles inside the area surrounded by the thick line includes $\infty$-vertex.

Can someone help?
[image]